# SQL + CI: How to join multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables `manufacturer` and `colors`.

In table `manufacturer`.

```
id      title
5       Audi
8       Toyota
11      Peugeot
```

In colors table I have multiple colors for manufacturer

```
id      car_id     color
1       5          red
2       5          blue
3       8          cyan
4       5          purple
5       8          dark_cyan
6       11         white
7       11         black
```

Problem is, how can I fetch results from database to show all colors for all cars?

I stich something like this..

```
$this->db->select('m.*, c.*');
$this->db->join('colors c', 'c.car_id = m.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('m.title');
$this->db->order_by('c.color', 'DESC');

return $this->db->get('manufacturer');
```

View

```
<?php foreach($all_colors->result() AS $color) : ?>

    <h4><?php echo $color->title; ?></h4>

    <?php echo $color->color; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So that it would be shown like this

```
- Audi
red
blue
purple

- Toyota
cyan
dark_cyan

- Peugeot
white
black
```

This my example will show only title and first color of that car... ?

```
- Audi
red

- Toyota
cyan

- Peugeot
white
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in the way you're fetching data. The only issue might be usage of aliases in these methods. Try to use raw query like this:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM manufacturer m left join colors c on c.car_id = m.id GROUP BY m.title ORDER BY c.color DESC");
return $q->result();
```

and then:

```
<?php foreach($all_colors->result() AS $color) : ?>
<h4><?php echo $color->title; ?></h4>
<?php echo $color->color; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or try to fetch data without aliases:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('colors', 'colors.car_id = manufacturer.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('manufacturer.title');
$this->db->order_by('colors.color', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('manufacturer');
```

Comment: Dude, I've been so disrespectful for you and didn't check your answer as correct after these years! So sorry..